# quotes(") in key for HMACSHA1

Tags: c#, hmacsha1

My string

```
string key = "lw!'s"lI1p,,7#P9IQ1b";
```

This key is used in my HMAC-SHA1 encoding

```
public string Encode(string input, string key)
{
    HMACSHA1 myhmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key));
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    byte[] hashValue = myhmacsha1.ComputeHash(stream);
    return hashValue.ToString();
}
```

Now the problem is my key has quote(") in it:

> lw!'s"lI1p,,7#P9IQ1b

I am not sure how to deal with " in the string

I tried using \ in

```
string key = "lw!'s\"lI1p,,7#P9IQ1b";
```

but it seems adding \ changes the key and the string produced after HMACSHA1 encryption is not what it should be.

Can someone please give me an idea of how to make it work.

Comment: `\"` is correct and corresponds to `lw!'s"lI1p,,7#P9IQ1b` - problem is elsewhere.

Comment: or you could do the following on `key = key.Replace("'", @"\'");`

Comment: Sure you want to interpret the input as ascii?

Comment: well this is part of web api call. The encoded value is send as a parameter for the web api request. I am consuming the api so i was doing what i was instructed.

Comment: Aslo what is wrong with interpreting the input as ascii?? Are there some limitation or,,?

Comment: ASCII.GetBytes("£") would produce an output different from say UTF8.GetBytes("£")

Comment: That makes sense. Let em try with  UTF8.GetBytes. hopefully it works. thanks Alex.